# python winrm connect using local account

Tags: python-2.7, winrm

I'm trying to connect to Windows server 2012 via python 2.7.13 on CentOS using winrm. The server is not part of a domain. I created a separate local administrator account to connect to it.

Used  `winrm configSDDL default` to provide that user all access.

Added my client machine to trusted hosts.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts


   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Client

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   TrustedHosts                                   172.27.150.95
```

Added exception in the firewall and made sure the service is up.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM-HTTP" dir=in localport=5985 protocol=TCP action=allow
Ok.

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Service -ComputerName abc -Name winrm | Select Status

                                                                                                                                                         Status
                                                                                                                                                         ------
                                                                                                                                                        Running


PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Client settings for winrm:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config/client
Client
    NetworkDelayms = 5000
    URLPrefix = wsman
    AllowUnencrypted = true
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Digest = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = false
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = 172.27.150.95
```

Telnet is working:

```
xyz:~ # telnet 172.27.148.29 5985
Trying 172.27.148.29...
Connected to abc (172.27.148.29).
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
xyz:~ #
```

But still:

```
>>> s = winrm.Session('abc', auth=('abc\script-runner', 'xxx'))                   
>>> r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/__init__.py", line 37, in run_cmd
    shell_id = self.protocol.open_shell()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 132, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 207, in send_message
    return self.transport.send_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 190, in send_message
    raise InvalidCredentialsError("the specified credentials were rejected by the server")
winrm.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError: the specified credentials were rejected by the server
>>>
```

Also, I enabled Auditing for failed/successful logons but I don't see either failed or success for my attempts to connect.

Please tell me what's missing? I want to connect via local user.

Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure in the target windows machine the network connection type is "private", if it is "public" winrm would not get configured.
2. Open command prompt and type:

   `winrm qc
   winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}`
3. Open Powershell and type:

   `enable-psremoting
   set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts *` 
   ('*' is for all hosts, you may specify the host you want)
4. In your python script:

   `import winrm
    s = winrm.Session('yourWindowsHost', auth=('yourLocalUser', 'passwordInPlainText'))
    r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])`

Comment: After weeks of trying to figure out why my credentials were getting rejected, this did it. I removed from domain, made sure it was private and followed these steps and then I could run win_ping module in ansible successfully. Thank you!